# Separating elements of a Pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like the following:

```
    Time  Measurement
0      0            1
1      1            2
2      2            3
3      3            4
4      4            5
5      0            2
6      1            3
7      2            4
8      3            5
9      4            6
10     0            3
11     1            4
12     2            5
13     3            6
14     4            7
15     0            1
16     1            2
17     2            3
18     3            4
19     4            5
20     0            2
21     1            3
22     2            4
23     3            5
24     4            6
25     0            3
26     1            4
27     2            5
28     3            6
29     4            7
```

which can be generated with the following code:

```
import pandas
time=[0,1,2,3,4]
repeat_1_conc_1=[1,2,3,4,5]
repeat_1_conc_2=[2,3,4,5,6]
repeat_1_conc_3=[3,4,5,6,7]
d1=pandas.DataFrame([time,repeat_1_conc_1]).transpose()
d2=pandas.DataFrame([time,repeat_1_conc_2]).transpose()
d3=pandas.DataFrame([time,repeat_1_conc_3]).transpose()
repeat_2_conc_1=[1,2,3,4,5]
repeat_2_conc_2=[2,3,4,5,6]
repeat_2_conc_3=[3,4,5,6,7]
d4=pandas.DataFrame([time,repeat_2_conc_1]).transpose()
d5=pandas.DataFrame([time,repeat_2_conc_2]).transpose()
d6=pandas.DataFrame([time,repeat_2_conc_3]).transpose()
df= pandas.concat([d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6]).reset_index()
df.drop('index',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.columns=['Time','Measurement']
print df
```

If you look at the code, you'll see that I have two experimental repeats in the same DataFrame which should be separated at `df.iloc[:15]`. Additionally, within each experiment I have 3 sub-experiments that can be thought of like the starting conditions of a dose response, i.e. first sub-experiment starts with 1, second with 2 and third with 3. These should be separated at index intervals of `len(time)', which is 0-4, 5 elements for each experimental repeat. Could somebody please tell me the best way to separate this data into individual time course measurements for each experiment? I'm not exactly sure what the best data structure  would be to use but I just need to be able to access each data for each sub experiment for each experimental repeat easily. Perhaps sometime like:

```
repeat1=
    Time  Measurement
0      0            1
1      1            2
2      2            3
3      3            4
4      4            5


5      0            2
6      1            3
7      2            4
8      3            5
9      4            6


10     0            3
11     1            4
12     2            5
13     3            6
14     4            7

Repeat 2=
      Time  Measurement
15     0            1
16     1            2
17     2            3
18     3            4
19     4            5


20     0            2
21     1            3
22     2            4
23     3            5
24     4            6


25     0            3
26     1            4
27     2            5
28     3            6
29     4            7
```

Comment: What are `repeat1` and `Repeat 2` - data frames? Or do you just want to print your DF separating it this way?

Comment: I don't know the best data structure to put this data in. But the criteria is that I need to be able to easily access each starting condition (subexperiment) for each repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you may set a multiindex so that you can index your DF accessing experiments and subexperiments easily:

```
In [261]: dfi = df.set_index([df.index//15+1, df.index//5 - df.index//15*3 + 1])

In [262]: dfi
Out[262]:
     Time  Measurement
1 1     0            1
  1     1            2
  1     2            3
  1     3            4
  1     4            5
  2     0            2
  2     1            3
  2     2            4
  2     3            5
  2     4            6
  3     0            3
  3     1            4
  3     2            5
  3     3            6
  3     4            7
2 1     0            1
  1     1            2
  1     2            3
  1     3            4
  1     4            5
  2     0            2
  2     1            3
  2     2            4
  2     3            5
  2     4            6
  3     0            3
  3     1            4
  3     2            5
  3     3            6
  3     4            7
```

selecting subexperiments

```
In [263]: dfi.loc[1,1]
Out[263]:
     Time  Measurement
1 1     0            1
  1     1            2
  1     2            3
  1     3            4
  1     4            5

In [264]: dfi.loc[2,2]
Out[264]:
     Time  Measurement
2 2     0            2
  2     1            3
  2     2            4
  2     3            5
  2     4            6
```

select second experiment with all subexperiments:

```
In [266]: dfi.loc[2,:]
Out[266]:
   Time  Measurement
1     0            1
1     1            2
1     2            3
1     3            4
1     4            5
2     0            2
2     1            3
2     2            4
2     3            5
2     4            6
3     0            3
3     1            4
3     2            5
3     3            6
3     4            7
```

alternatively you can create your own slicing function:

```
def my_slice(rep=1, subexp=1):
    rep -= 1
    subexp -= 1
    return df.ix[rep*15 + subexp*5 : rep*15 + subexp*5 + 4, :]
```

demo:

```
In [174]: my_slice(1,1)
Out[174]:
   Time  Measurement
0     0            1
1     1            2
2     2            3
3     3            4
4     4            5

In [175]: my_slice(2,1)
Out[175]:
    Time  Measurement
15     0            1
16     1            2
17     2            3
18     3            4
19     4            5

In [176]: my_slice(2,2)
Out[176]:
    Time  Measurement
20     0            2
21     1            3
22     2            4
23     3            5
24     4            6
```

PS bit more convenient way to concatenate your DFs:

```
df = pandas.concat([d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6], ignore_index=True)
```

so you don't need the following `.reset_index()` and `drop()`

Comment: Fantastic, just what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @user3059024, you are welcome! :) Thanks for accepting the answer!